# Select from a table using a reference from a linked table (Join within a Join?)

Tags: mysql, join

So I'm altering a Foreign Key in my Database, which for the most part is going smoothly. However, there is one query I've come across that won't work with the new FK reference.

I've built a quick [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2e2376) to show the skeleton of the table structures.

Basically the query I am trying to work out, is the `cable` used to reference the `major` table, but now references the `sub` table instead (as built in the fiddle). However, this query references the `area` table as well, and I'm not sure how to keep that reference now that the `cable` table doesn't reference the `major` table anymore.

The query in question looks like this:

```
SELECT
  C.name,
  M.name AS Origin,
  M.area AS OriginArea
FROM cable C
  INNER JOIN major M ON C.major = M.major_id
WHERE
  # Parameters
;
```

But now, because the `cable` table references the `sub` table I don't know how to reference the `major` table to select the `area`?

Maybe something like this?

```
SELECT
  C.name,
  S.name AS Origin,
  M.area AS OriginArea
FROM cable C
  INNER JOIN sub S ON C.sub = S.sub_id
  INNER JOIN major M ON S.major = M.major_id
WHERE
  # Parameters
;
```

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something, but I don't see how foreign key references would have anything to do with a join query between tables not working.

Comment: Whatever you do, don't invalidate the work of the answerer guy. If you truly have a new question, don't torpedo his efforts.

Comment: @Drew well from the original question, he basically just said "yup, that works". So while this kinda does invalidate his answer (which I do regret), the answer is now pretty much invalid. So since Tim advised I should combine my new question with the original, I'm not sure what to do! D:

Comment: I am saying if you changed the conditions of the question, just go with your new question you posted 20 minutes or so ago. If your original question was answered fine by Mahesh, show him his propers. Over and out :p

Comment: @Tim ok, I'll try to clarify it, and if you feel the explanation should be added to the question, I'll do so. Have you had a look at the fiddle I linked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should work

```
SELECT   C.name,   S.name AS Origin,   M.area AS OriginArea FROM cable C   INNER JOIN sub S ON C.sub = S.sub_id   INNER JOIN major M ON S.major = M.major_id;
+---------+--------+------------+
| name    | Origin | OriginArea |
+---------+--------+------------+
| cable 1 | sub 1  |          1 |
+---------+--------+------------+
1 row in set (0.07 sec)
```