# SQL Query to JOIN based on Heirarchical data

Tags: mysql, join

Ok so following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38092329/select-from-a-table-using-a-reference-from-a-linked-table-join-within-a-join), I have realised that the JOIN I am attempting is unfortunately not so straight forward.

To amend the previous query, the foreign keys within the table create a hierarchy, and the reference is only populated if the entry is at the top level.

So what I need to achieve, is get the `area.name` for the cable (using [this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/43d520/1)) entry, but I don't need the rest of the hierarchy in my selection.

Obviously, my previous attempt missed the fact that the `major_parent` field was sometimes empty.

This is my original query:

```
SELECT
  C.name,
  S.name AS Origin,
  M.area AS OriginArea
FROM cable C
  INNER JOIN sub S ON C.sub = S.sub_id
  INNER JOIN major M ON S.major_parent = M.major_id
WHERE
  # Parameters
;
```

Comment: I think you should stick with your original question, since it appears the problem has not changed.  If you really want to ask a second time, you should at least show us sample input, output, and any attempt you have made.

Comment: @Tim ok, I'll add this onto the original and get rid of this.

Comment: it looks like an interesting question, maybe I will look at the first one now.

Comment: answered in the first one, or should I rather post into this one?

Comment: @Philipp I have [posted on meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/327157/i-have-new-information-about-the-same-question-which-changes-the-answer-do-i-a) because I'm confused too! D:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/43d520/6) for this query:

```
SELECT
    cable.`name`,
    sub.`name`,
    major.`name`,
    major.area
FROM
    cable
INNER JOIN sub 
        ON cable.sub = sub.sub_id
LEFT JOIN sub AS parent 
        ON parent.sub_id = sub.sub_parent
INNER JOIN major 
        ON major.major_id = COALESCE (parent.major_parent,sub.major_parent)
INNER JOIN area 
        ON area.area_id = major.area
```

This way your hierarchy becomes something optional. If the entry in `sub` has a parent the left join will find it, if it doesn't the left join will return `null` but `COALESCE (parent.major_parent, sub.major_parent)` will just skip the `null` and use the `sub.major_parent` to join the `major` table.

**Edit**

I think I messed up the join to the parent sub by using the `sub_parent = major_parent`. It should be `sub_parent = sub_id` shouldn't it?

```
LEFT JOIN sub AS parent 
        ON parent.sub_id = sub.sub_parent
```

Also added it to the whole query on top.

Comment: @Phillipp I'm having some issues with this - just adapting it to my own data. Is it possible you could give me a hand with this at some point? We can create a chat room to avoid clogging up the comments, and if anything changes the question/answer, we can edit them in

Comment: Yes we can do that.